# Getting a TypeError in Node.js when trying to update a property on a Mongo document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, crud

I am trying to update a document in MongoDB that are stored as an array value for the key "tokens". I keep getting a TypeError: Cannot set property 'reviews' of undefined when I try to update the reviews. From reading the documents for Mongo and the Node driver it looks like I have set the filter correctly but it still seems like update doesn't know which document to do the operation on.

The error:
`TypeError: Cannot set property 'tokens' of undefined`

This is the code I have:

```
var tokenDoc = {
  uid: name,
  comment: comment,
  source: source,
  date: Date.now()
}

database.collection("item").updateOne(
  {_id: itemId},
  {$set: {tokens: tokenDoc}},
  {upsert: true}
)
```

I am stuck and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more code. I don't currently see any occurrence of 'reviews'. What type does it have? How do you get it? How are you trying to update it?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, The error should have read "tokens" and not "reviews". The error reads correctly now.